# What is latest in Appium version for iOS and Android?

Tags: appium

What is new in Appium 1.13 version, can the same be used for automating both Android and iOS apps

Answer (score 0):

There were few extra capabilities are added for Android. Appium is for Automating both iOS and Android. Please check the release notes here :

[Appium Release V1.13](https://github.com/appium/appium/releases?after=v1.13.1-rc.2)